# Creating Extent of Data within Raster (not just boundary of raster) in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, extents, geotiff-tiff

I have a tif (raster) that I need to generate a polygon around the data within the tif, not just the extent of the entire raster. The image below shows the type of data I am working with. I have ArcGIS 10.5 with 3D Analyst and Spatial Analyst extensions.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to [reclassify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) all cells that have a value to 1 and the leave `nodata` as `nodata`, so you end up with a binary raster of 1 or `nodata`. Then use the [raster to polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) tool to convert it to a polygon.